# import dump.sql file into postresql

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am new to PostgreSQL. I have a file name dump.sql. I want to import this into my POstgreSQL database. I created the database using `CREATE database_name`. Then I used `psql database_name < /Downloads/web-task/dump.sql`. After running this command it shows not output. I assume it did not import anything from dump.sql. **How can I import this file into my PostgreSQL DB?**

Comment: Do not assume anything. It is normal for commands such as these to not display anything when they run successfully. _Look_ inside your database to see if the data is there.

Comment: How can I see inside that database? Could you please tell me which command can I use to see? I am new to PGSQL.

Comment: You can simply use `psql database_name`. It should give you an SQL prompt where you can type commands such as `SELECT * FROM <some table you imported>`

Comment: OK but I do not know the table name. I just imported dump.sql file into my database.

Comment: Well then read the dump.sql file, and look for a table name that you can test ?

Comment: Still it does not return anything after running SELECT * FROM regions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35332/discussion-between-miklos-aubert-and-2619)

Comment: Connect with `psql` and use the `\d` command to list table(s)

Comment: It doesn't show any tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have determined in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35332/discussion-between-miklos-aubert-and-2619) that you were trying to import your dump.sql file from within the `psql` prompt, which obviously couldn't work... The data is now imported.